# Is it possible to query MS Graph for a list of groups that contains the number of members in the group?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-groups

I can't find any mention of this in the documentation. Can this be done without actually fetching the group members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have fetch the group members. There is a $count feature

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

but it is not supported for groups

Note: $count is not supported for collections of resources that derive from directoryObject like collections of users or groups.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#count-parameter